# Alternative to (obsolete) GetValue and SetValue methods

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dependency-properties

I am trying to get and set a DependencyProperty. The DependencyProperty is being used to describe a mask for a regex statement, used to control user input in a textbox. The code in question is as follows:

```
public string Mask
{
     get { return (string)GetValue(MaskProperty); }
     set { SetValue(MaskProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty MaskProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("Mask", typeof(string), typeof(MaskTextBox), new PropertyMetadaa(string.Empty));
```

Everything *seems* to be working, except GetValue and SetValue. Now, I know that I could use the System.Workflow namespace to get these to work, but I also know that the namespace is obsolete, so I would rather not use it.

It seems that the System.Activities namespace is designed as an up to date alternative to System.Workflow, so with that in mind, is there a System.Activities alternative to the GetValue and SetValue methods? If not, what is an effective alternative to those methods?

Comment: What? Is your class derived from [DependencyObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject(v=vs.110).aspx)? That class provides the backbone for WPFs Get/SetValue logistics ...

Comment: The class itself is derived from the TextBox object, a part of the System.Windows.Forms namespace.

Comment: WindowsForms != WPF  -  The windform elements do not derive from DependencyObject - you are mixing technologies here that are hardly mixable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any class that should be included into WPFs binding mechanisms needs to be derived from [DependencyObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject(v=vs.110).aspx) or one of its Childclasses:

> ```
> System.Object
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject
>     System.Windows.DependencyObject
>       System.Windows.ContentElement
>       System.Windows.Controls.DataGridColumn
>       System.Windows.Controls.GridViewColumn
>       System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.Primitives.StarLayoutInfo
>       System.Windows.Controls.TextSearch
>       System.Windows.Controls.ViewBase
>       System.Windows.Data.BindingGroup
>       System.Windows.Data.CollectionContainer
>       System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource
>       System.Windows.Freezable
>       System.Windows.Ink.GestureRecognizer
>       System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Visual3D
>       System.Windows.Media.Visual
>       System.Windows.Navigation.JournalEntry
>       System.Windows.TriggerAction
>       System.Windows.TriggerBase
>       System.Windows.VisualState
>       System.Windows.VisualStateGroup
>       System.Windows.VisualStateManager
>       System.Windows.VisualTransition
> ```

(WPF uses further derived ones to for the WPF-things like TextBox etc - they are below UIElement/[FrameWorkElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement(v=vs.110).aspx)).

The DependencyObject provides the GetValue/SetValue methods you need to implement DependencyPropertys.

---

You can not simply put a DependencyProperty in a Winforms-Class and think it will work - well you can do, but it wont. The underlying plumbing is simply not present.

Comment: This seems to be what I am looking for! Also, this has made it clear to me that I am horrendously lacking in my knowledge of WPF versus Winforms. Do you know of any good resources that might help me make more sense of it?

Comment: @MrSpudtastic - sorry, no idea about wpf tutorials, but google should put out a few, asking for tuts here is considers OT so better not use a new question for that. you might also have a look at channel9 or microsoft academy for related material but as I said: no idea where to get good ones. Maybe also look at MS sites like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/getting-started/walkthrough-my-first-wpf-desktop-application